# Centered Suggested Input Overlay

Tags: javascript, html, input, search-suggestion

I want to create a search bar similar to that of Google, where a suggested search will have a search suggestion viewing in your current input line.

I can achieve this by putting a similarly positioned input element exactly behind the first and giving disabled and tinted font-color attributes. Then I can actively parse the string from the active input and edit the disabled input behind it.

The catch is that my current search bar is centered, which will cause any suggested text to become misaligned with the active input.  Any ideas as to adjust the suggestion input to align with the active input?

**UPDATE:**

I realize that I was very rushed to get this posted and that has made my intentions very unclear. I apologize for any misconceptions and efforts made to answer this poorly written question.

Anyways, I have created a suggestion preview that shows behind the typed text. This works when the text is aligned in the middle of the input bar.

```js
$suggestion = $("#suggestion");
$action = $("#action").focus();

$action.on("keyup", function() {
  var text = $action.val();
  
  if(text == "") $suggestion.val("");
  else $suggestion.val(text + " suggestion");
});
$action.on("blur", function() {
  $suggestion.val("");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#suggestion {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
}

#action {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="suggestion" disabled>
<input id="action">
```

However, if you center the text inside the input bar, then all the characters become misaligned as shown in the demo below:

```js
$suggestion = $("#suggestion");
$action = $("#action").focus();

$action.on("keyup", function() {
  var text = $action.val();
  
  if(text == "") $suggestion.val("");
  else $suggestion.val(text + " suggestion");
});
$action.on("blur", function() {
  $suggestion.val("");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#suggestion {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #777;
}

#action {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="suggestion" disabled>
<input id="action">
```

I am looking for a way to keep the input text aligned in the middle while still being able to dynamically align suggestion text behind it for a suggestion view.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @BenjaminBrownlee can you tell me your first issue that overlay text does not seem properly and it will not hide when cursor focus on textbox right?

Comment: I can get those features working later. I am more worried about lining up the text when the input text align is centered.

Comment: @BenjaminBrownlee Please let me know whether it's helpul or not

Comment: You sure are aware that 'keypress' event doesnt capture `backspace`??

Comment: I updated my question to be a lot more clear. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

```css
*{
    font-family: "arial";
    font-size: 12px;
}

#tags{
  padding:5px;
  width:200px;
}

.wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px auto;
    left: 150px;
    top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <input id="tags" placeholder="Search by language" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the suggestion style that I am looking for.

Comment: Then can you add your concrete requirement. I shall help you well.